# nix-shell can't find standard attribute

Tags: nix, nixos, nix-shell

I'm running nixos 19.09 and trying to follow along with the [instructions](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/ruby.section.md) for creating a ruby package. But in one of the first steps I'm getting an error that the `withPackages` attribute can't be found.

Command:
`$ nix-shell -p "ruby.withPackages (ps: with ps; [ nokogiri pry ])" --show-trace`

Result:

```
while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'shell' at /nix/store/b6cqdsczmwxfkmc65483x7fgwdl129ar-nixpkgs-19.03.173684.c8db7a8a16e/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:7:14:
while evaluating 'getOutput' at /nix/store/b6cqdsczmwxfkmc65483x7fgwdl129ar-nixpkgs-19.03.173684.c8db7a8a16e/nixpkgs/lib/attrsets.nix:464:23, called from undefined position:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/b6cqdsczmwxfkmc65483x7fgwdl129ar-nixpkgs-19.03.173684.c8db7a8a16e/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:141:17, called from undefined position:
attribute 'withPackages' missing, at (string):1:94
```

I'm guessing that I messed up my nix store somehow, but I don't know how to debug it.

*Additional Info*:

```
$ echo $NIX_PATH
$HOME/.nix-defexpr/channels:nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

```
$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.03
unstable https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable
```

```
$ sudo nix-channel --list
<blank>
```

Comment: Looks like you're actually using 19.03. Please `echo $NIX_PATH`, `nix-channel --list` and `sudo nix-channel --list`

Comment: interesting. I was going off of `system.stateVersion = "19.09"` in configuration.nix. I pasted the outputs in the question for nicer formatting. @RobertHensing

Answer (score 0):

After @RobertHensing pointed out that it looked like I was on 19.03, and asked me to print out my channels, I tried just updating the channel list to point to [19.09](https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.09) instead of [19.03](https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.03) (with `nix-channel --add`) and that fixed it.